# Apache2 site not available from the internet

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, apache2

I have searched long and hard and run through many tutorials and cannot find an answer. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

I have:

- virtualbox vm running ubuntu 16.04 fully up to date apache2 installed
- fully up to date wordpress installed fully up to date
- port forwarding on port 80 set up and tested on my router (testing using web services and seeing traffic on port 80 going back and forth on tcpdump when I try to access the page from a browser (no traffic being seen at any other time))
- iptables set up to allow traffic in and out on port 80
- ddns from noip.com set up and tested

My problem:

I can access the wordpress webpage I installed in /var/www/html from anywhere on my local network with no issues. When I try to access it from the internet the page will only ever time out. I can also ssh into the vm with no problem.

Some of my settings:

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
                <Directory />
                        Options FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride None
                </Directory>
                <Directory /var/www/html/>
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
                        AllowOverride None
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

iptables (I have also tried running iptables -F to clear the rules and setting all policies to accept but that makes no difference):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport http -j ACCEPT
```

ports.conf and apache2.conf are both on their default settings.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue ultimately was but despite careful testing it seemed to randomly fix itself.